# Javascript use very much of memory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a diagram with canvas on my website that it change real time. Every 5 second ajax call a function that get data from database and give them to another function to make canvas. After  a short while firefox ram usage get up to 300MB and also get larger. What and where is problem? How can i fix this problem? Here is my script:

```
function submitIpRequest(interval) {
if (!interval) {
    switchIpdlCallChartInterval (false);
}

var formValues = $('#IpRequest').serialize();
//wait();
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : baseUrl + 'monitoring/ipdl-call-chart',
    data : formValues,
    success : function(response) {
            //waitStop();

            var resultFull = $.parseJSON(response);

            if (resultFull.msg) {
                jqError( resultFull.msg, (resultFull.severity)?(resultFull.severity):('Error'));
                return;
            }

            _disableIpdlCallFilterShowIcon ();

            var result = resultFull.data;
            if (0 == result.length) {
                jqError( _("No data found for the given period of time"), "Warning");
                return;
            }

            var timeInterval = $('#ipdlTimeInterval').val();
            var markerValue = false;

            switch (timeInterval){
                case 'minute': 
                    dateFormat = '%y-%#m-%#d %H:%M';
                    dateTickInterval = (Math.floor(resultFull.mDIA/10)+1) + ' minutes';
                    break;
                case 'hour': 
                    dateFormat = '%y-%#m-%#d %H:%M';
                    dateTickInterval = (Math.floor(resultFull.mDIA/10)+1) + ' hours';
                    console.log(dateTickInterval);
                    break;
                case 'day': 
                    dateFormat = '%y-%#m-%#d';
                    dateTickInterval = (Math.floor(resultFull.mDIA/10)+1) + ' days';
                    break;  
                case 'month': 
                    dateFormat = '%y-%#m';
                    dateTickInterval = (Math.floor(resultFull.mDIA/10)+1) + ' months';
                    break;
                case 'year':
                    dateFormat = '%y';
                    dateTickInterval = '1 year';
                    markerValue = true;
                    break;
            }

            xaxisOptions = 
            {
                renderer: ( 'year' == timeInterval) ? ($.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer) : ($.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer),
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions:{
                    formatString: ( 'year' == timeInterval) ? (null) : (dateFormat),
                    angle:-90,
                        },
                min: ( resultFull.max == resultFull.min ) ? (null) : (resultFull.min),
                max: ( resultFull.max == resultFull.min ) ? (null) : (resultFull.max),
                tickInterval: ( 'year' == timeInterval) ? (null) : (dateTickInterval)
            };

            $('#ipRequestChart').html('');
            ipdlCallChart = $.jqplot('ipRequestChart', [result], {
                seriesDefaults: {
                    lineWidth:2, 
                    showMarker:markerValue,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        padding: 10
                    }
                },
                height:"250px",
                axes:{
                    xaxis:xaxisOptions,
                    yaxis:{
                        rendererOptions : {
                            tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
                        },
                        numberTicks : 1,
                        tickOptions:{
                            formatString:'%i'
                        },
                        min: 0,
                    }
                },
                highlighter : {
                    show : true,
                    sizeAdjust : 2,
                    tooltipAxes : 'both',
                    useAxesFormatters : true,
                }
          });
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textstatus, error) {
        waitStop();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: please check if this helps you, https://forum.jquery.com/topic/memory-leaks-with-ajax-calls

Comment: Thanks you. But this was not useful for me.

Comment: You have a memory leak in either jqplot (i doubt it was designed for such intensive use), or in way how you clear #ipRequestChart (why html(''), just call .remove()), or in use of global variable ipdlCallChart (check it's usages or make it local).

Comment: I have to use this way because i use this function in some another functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I solved it. I don't know why but it seems javascript's garbage doesn't work when a script call itself by time out. I undefined my variables by:

```
my_variable = undefined;
```

just after last use of it.